# How to create a callable function pointer to a function that has variadic arguments?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, variadic-templates

I have the following function

```
template <typename... Args>
void func(Args&&... args){
  // do stuff
}
```

I now want to create a function pointer, that is callable with a variadic list of arguments, just like the function itself.

```
template <typename... Args>
using Var_Func = void(*)(Args... args)
```

At this point, I'm stuck. When creating a variable of type `Var_Func`, I have to give a list of types for the template:

```
Var_Func<[List of types]> var_func_p = &func;
```

This, however, prevents me from calling the pointer with a true variadic list of arguments. I want a pointer, that allows me to call it like a true variadic function, like this:

```
var_func_p("Test");
var_func_p(0.3, 5);
var_func_p('c', "Another test", 1.3, 3);
```

I have no idea how to achieve this. Can someone help me?

Comment: what do you need it for? Function pointers point to functions of one specific type. Different instantiations of that template are of different type. [xy problem](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=xy+problem) ?

Comment: your naming is a bit confusing, `func` for the function and for the pointer.  Why do you think you need the pointer? Can't you just call the function directly?

Comment: Usually when I find myself in a situation like this I've got a design error. But when I don't,  try to abstract away the variability with a [functor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/what-are-c-functors-and-their-uses).

Answer (score 3):

`func` isn't actually a function. It's a template that the compiler can use to create new functions when it needs to.

When you do `func(5)` the compiler creates a function called `func<int>` and then calls it. When you do `func(5.0, 'a')` the compiler creates a function called `func<double, char>` and then calls it. These are two completely different, unrelated functions with two different types.

You can create a pointer to `func<int>` or `func<double, char>` or `func<>` or `func<anything else>` in the usual way. But you cannot ever create a pointer to `func`, because `func` is not a function, it's an instruction for the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, this is not possible.

A function template is not a function, it's a template *of* a function -- and thus it does not have a function pointer until you specify which instantiation you want. At which point, the pointer is fixed to a specific number of arguments of specific types.

It is **not possible** in the C++ language to type-erase templates into a singular type, such as a pointer that you can pass around and lazily instantiate.

That is, code such as:

```
some_discrete_variadic_type x = var_func_1;
x(1);
x(1, "2");
x = var_func_2;
x(1);
x(1, "2");
```

Is not possible, because for type-erasure to work you must normalize the erasure to a fixed number of types (in this case, it would be instantiations).

---

Depending on what the problem is you are trying to solve, however, there might be workarounds -- though this would require more information.

If your uses are more limited -- such as to pass the functionality *into* other functions that are only ever known at compile-time, then you can use Functor objects instead and pass them into function templates where the arguments are deduced. For example:

```cpp
struct var_func
{
    template <typename...Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&...args) -> void
    {
        // do something
    }
};
```

Where an example of it being called could be:

```cpp
template <typename T>
auto consume(T var_func_p) -> void
{
    var_func_p("Test");
    var_func_p(0.3, 5);
    var_func_p('c', "Another test", 1.3, 3);
}

int main()
{
    consume(var_func{});
    consume(some_other_var_func{});
}
```

Note that in this case, you're not passing a function template around anymore. You're passing a static object, `var_func`, which contains a call-operator (`operator()`) that is a function template.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will give this a try.

What is the meaning of "-> void" after consume and the operator overload?

Comment: It's just a different way of writing the [return type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function) that was introduced in c++11. `auto consume(T var_func_p) -> void` is the same as writing `void consume(T var_func_p)`. Sorry for being confusing; it's just how I typically write C++ these days.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
template <typename... Args>
void func(Args&&... args){
  // do stuff
}

template <typename... Args>
using f_ptr = void(*)(Args&&...);

int main() {
    f_ptr<int,int> p = &func<int,int>;
    p(3,1);
}
```

However, pointers to different instantations of `func` are incompatible.

> This, however, prevents me to call the pointer with a true variadic list of arguments. I want a pointer, that allows me to call it like a true variadic function, like this:

You cannot store a pointer to eg `func<double,double>` in a `f_ptr<int,int>`.